# Split string with ' in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

How to split this string

```
1014,'0,1031,1032,1034,1035,1036',0,0,1,1,0,1,0,-1,1
```

and get this string array as result

```
1014
'0,1031,1032,1034,1035,1036'
0
0
1
1
0
1
0
-1
1
```

in C#

Comment: calling a regex pro!, check out the various CSV parsers out there, they all handle this (and more). http://www.filehelpers.com/

Comment: Normally when a string is split, the pivot character(s) are removed.  In this case, the second result is contained within the apostrophes.  Will there ever be more than two apostrophes in the input string?  If so, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
string line ="1014,'0,1031,1032,1034,1035,1036',0,0,1,1,0,1,0,-1,1" ;
var values = Regex.Matches(line, "(?:'(?<m>[^']*)')|(?<m>[^,]+)");
foreach (Match value in values) {
  Console.WriteLine(value.Groups["m"].Value);
}
```

Comment: This answer does not keep the quotes - as the question asks to do.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that this regex should give you what you are looking for:

```
('(?:[^']|'')*'|[^',\r\n]*)(,|\r\n?|\n)?
```

http://regexr.com?2vib4

EDIT:

Quick code snippet on how it might work:

```
 var rx = new Regex("('(?:[^']|'')*'|[^',\r\n]*)(,|\r\n?|\n)?");
 var text= "1014,'0,1031,1032,1034,1035,1036',0,0,1,1,0,1,0,-1,1";

 var matches = rx.Matches(text);

 foreach (Match match in matches)
 {
     System.Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].ToString());
 }
```

Comment: This is the best answer, since it takes care of multiple strings within the string. And keeps the quotes.

Comment: @NoLifeKing I would definitely tend to agree :)

Answer (score 1):

This code is not pretty at all, but it works. :) (Does not work with multiple "strings" within the string.)

```
void Main()
{
    string stuff = "1014,'0,1031,1032,1034,1035,1036',0,0,1,1,0,1,0,-1,1";
    List<string> newStuff = new List<string>();

    var extract = stuff.Substring(stuff.IndexOf('\''), stuff.IndexOf('\'', stuff.IndexOf('\'') + 1) - stuff.IndexOf('\'') + 1);
    var oldExtract = extract;
    extract = extract.Replace(',',';');
    stuff = stuff.Replace(oldExtract, extract);
    newStuff.AddRange(stuff.Split(new[] {','}));
    var newList = newStuff;
    for(var i = 0; i < newList.Count; i++)
        newList[i] = newList[i].Replace(';',',');
    // And newList will be in the format you specified, but in a list..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly split a string on `'` (single) quote and then after go for `comma` (,).

Comment: ... only splitting even-indexed strings, and surrounding odd-indexed strings with single quotes again. Then concatenating all the results as a single array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a parser, you don't need Regex.  Here's a pretty simple version that works perfectly:

```
var splits = input
            .Split('\'')
            .SelectMany(
                (s,i) => (i%2==0) 
                ? s.Split(new[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) 
                : new[]{ "'" + s + "'"}
            );
```

This is exactly what @AVD + @Rawling described ... Split on `'`, and split only "even" results, then combine.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO; //Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

public class Sample {
    static void Main(){
        string data = "1014,'0,1031,1032,1034,1035,1036',0,0,1,1,0,1,0,-1,1";
        string[] fields = null;
        data = data.Replace('\'', '"');
        using(var csvReader = new TextFieldParser(new StringReader(data))){
            csvReader.SetDelimiters(new string[] {","});
            csvReader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
            fields = csvReader.ReadFields();
        }
        foreach(var item in fields){
            Console.WriteLine("{0}",item);
        }
    }
}
```